# how to pass multiple activities by swiping with finger?

Tags: android

I am doing a kids apps,here i want to pass multiple pages(activities) by swiping with finger,because its user friendly especially for kids.So i tried with horizontal page controller ,but here i am able to pass only views like textview,imageview,...Here each view considering as a page.but i have to pass activities.And these activities i need to add myviews.so i am creating xml files dynamically.
So please suggest me ,how can i pass multiple activities by swiping.or else please let me know other than horizontal page controller.......

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a [ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html).

Answer (score 1):

My approach to this would be to create `Fragments` (rather than `Activities`) from the v4 compatibility jar and use a `ViewPager`

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

Comment: http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/android-page-swiping-using-viewpager/

Comment: yes i tried viewpager,i tried example in this link,but unable to do this one,getting so many errors,so i choosed horizontal page controller..... ,http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/android-page-swiping-using-viewpager/.........

Comment: i tried this example  previously ,but getting so many errors:(